# Stencil Start Error "Error: components\\stencil\\maintenanceNotice\\component.scss doesn\'t exist!\"

Tags: bigcommerce, stencil-buffer, stencils

I've come across this error message when I run "stencil start".  Any advise?

```
{ Error: components\stencil\maintenanceNotice\component.scss doesn't exist!
at options.error (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@bigcommerce\node-sass\lib\index.js:277:32)
  formatted: 'Error: components\\stencil\\maintenanceNotice\\component.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 160 of components/components.scss\n>> @import "stencil/maintenanceNotice/component";\n   --------^\n',
  message: 'components\\stencil\\maintenanceNotice\\component.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 160,
  file: 'components/components.scss',
  status: 1 }
```

Comment: Have you tried updating stencil or downloading cornerstone and replacing the template files?

Comment: I've tried to update stencil.. the error was still the same.. but I've tried the second option that you suggested and it works! Thanks!